# How to prevent the daemon thread suspend to the breakpoints?

Tags: eclipse

Even I selected the Skip All Breakpoints command in eclipse? The daemon thread will still be suspended when it has errors.
You can see the first picture, I have skipped the breakpoints.
[image]

But when the exceptions in the thread that I do not cared about occurred, the thread was still be debugged. How can I prevent it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution, just open the eclipse preference->java->debug->Suspend Exception, you will find it.